# Submit an html form using jQuery with textarea and validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<form  action="" class="form-horizontal" id="submitForm">
  <input class="required input-xxlarge" type="text" placeholder="Please enter a suitable title" name="title">
  <br><br>
  <div id='container' class="well">
    <br>
    <textarea class="span8 required" id='mytextarea' wrap='on'>
      Please enter some value
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit">
  </div>

</form>
```

When the user clicks submit, I want to send the textarea data as well as the text data to a url. I am also using the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), just to ensure client side verification.

And the following is my jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#submitForm").submit(function(){
        if ($("#submitForm").validate()){
            $.post("/create/post/",
                   {'data':$('#mytextarea').val()},
                   function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                       alert(data);
                   });
        }
    });
    });
```

As of now it does not seem to work, what is wrong? How can I override the submit button, perform validation and then post the data to the server?

Comment: As Simon said below, `validate()` is not supposed to be put inside your handler.  The validation is not properly initialized when you do that.  Then every time `submit` is clicked, it's re-initialized unnecessarily.  See his answer for the more proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) is just the initialization method for the plugin, not the one supposed to be used to check if the form is valid. Your provided code always "validates" to true, because `validate()` returns the validation object. The actual check to see whether the form is valid is what [`valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) is for.

In addition, as [Demao wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586351/342156), you need to stop the event propagation so the form is submitted with ajax. One way is by returning false at the end of the callback.

So your code should be something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitForm").validate();

    $("#submitForm").submit(function(){                       
        if ($("#submitForm").valid()){
            $.post("/create/post/",
                   {'data':$('#mytextarea').val()},
                   function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                       alert(data);
                   });
        }
        return false;
    });
 });​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hzcF7/

Another way to do this would be to let the plugin do the validation itself and just tell it what to do if the form is valid, using the `submitHandler` option when you initialize the validation object. Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
            $.post("/create/post/",
               {'data':$('#mytextarea').val()},
               function(data){
                   console.log(data);
                   alert(data);
               });
        }
    });
 });​​​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzcF7/1/)

Comment: I'd prefer jQuery's `preventDefault()` in this case; or your second example even better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return false or do an event stop propagation.  Right now the function continues the normal process of submitting a form after it starts the AJAX.  You just need to tell it to stop

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitForm").submit(function(){
        if ($("#submitForm").validate()){
            $.post("/create/post/",
                   {'data':$('#mytextarea').val()},
                   function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                       alert(data);
                   });
        }
        return false;
    });
    });
```